# How ro Return a boolean in Get Response body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I'm writing a  get API method: at the moment my API returns success 200 if the result is true and if it's false return 400.
But in response response body I'm getting no content 200: I'm trying to return success True  with 200 success :
API :

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[HttpGet]
[Route("tenants/{tenantId:Guid}/cpgofferstatus/{advertOfferId:Guid}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> statusCheck([FromUri] Guid tenantId, [FromUri] Guid advertOfferId)
{
   var result = await _digitalOffersDataProvider.CpgOfferStatus(tenantId, advertOfferId).ConfigureAwait(false);
           
   return Request.CreateResponse(result ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Data Provider Logic:

```
public async Task<bool> CpgOfferStatus(Guid tenantId, Guid advertOfferId)
{
    try
    {   
        var result= await _offerRepository.CpgOfferStatus(tenantId, advertOfferId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //"throw some exception, Intentionally I didn't add here  "
    }
    //...
}
```

API response:

```
Response Body
no content
Response Code
200
```

My intention is to return Response Body as True

Comment: `new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent("True") };` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
return result ? 
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true) : 
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, false);
```